# How can i make my game GUI look nicer?

Tags: graphics, gui

Im currently developing my first little android game. Its a casual game, which people can play when they are waiting for the bus or something like that.

All the other games in the playstores are looking very simple and still beautifull or addicting. So how can i improve my UI ? Are there any guidelines ?

The gallery contains several images of my GUI. Some are the same, but with other colors. Thats because i have an ingame shop, where the user can unlock new color themes.

[Open Imgur Gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kyR3.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it already looks real nice!
If you want it to look more complex (though I don't see a reason why) you could add borders to the geometric shapes that are darker in colour, eg a a darker border around the circles. 
You can play with the thickness of said border, you can make things stand out as foreground objects by making it thick and real dark, and you can make things stand out as background objects by making the border thin and slightly lighter.
They kind of do that in "Bindin of Isaac"

But yet again I already think it looks nice!

Not gonna upvote your question though because it's very subjective, we don't deal with those kind of open questions here on SE

Answer (score 0):

To Agree with Derpinator, I also think it looks quite nice already. But to improve your flat-like interface further, you could try experimenting more with different colour gradients to provide some more flair to your designs. Also maybe experiment with different background colours as well. Currently you are using both black and dark grey in your designs, which are somewhat boring colours to look at, maybe other colours will look more lively in that regard.

Keep up the good work!